# Java WSS Connection Could not create transport exception

Tags: java, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm so stuck about this.

I want to subscribe an ActiveMQ topic. ActiveMQ works on Centos machine, **NOT LOCALHOST**. I can consume messages with tcp, http protocols. Code;

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
    PropertyUtils.loadPropertyFile();
    Properties receiverProperties = PropertyUtils.getreceiverProperties();

    // URL of the JMS server
    String url = (String) receiverProperties.get("receiver.connection.url");

    // Name of the queue we will receive messages from
    String subject = (String) receiverProperties.get("receiver.topic.name");

    // Getting JMS connection from the server
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    // Creating session for getting messages
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // Getting the topic
    Destination destination = session.createTopic(subject);

    // MessageConsumer is used for receiving (consuming) messages
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
    Message message = null;

    // Here we receive the message.
    while (true) {
        message = consumer.receive();
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Received message '" + textMessage.getText() + "'");
        }
    }

    // We will be using TestMessage in our example. MessageProducer sent us a
    // TextMessage
    // so we must cast to it to get access to its .getText() method.
    // connection.close();
}
```

I want to use wss protocol. This is a must for me. When I changed url with wss://host:port getting;

```
Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: createTransport() method not implemented!
```

So I checked the alternatives. People figure this out with Stomp over WS. My first achievement is wss connection.

**Any** recommendation will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to use the ActiveMQ JMS client to connect to the STOMP transport connector?

Comment: What language and STOMP client implementation will you be using to connect?

Comment: @TimBish Yes Tim. But that is my second achievement. I'm testing all connectors. First of all I will go for wss connector.

Comment: @JustinBertram I'll use Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you're seeing is expected because the OpenWire JMS client you're using doesn't support WebSocket connections, and it doesn't really need to. WebSocket connections are really only relevant for clients running in a limited environment like a web browser. Web browsers don't support running Java clients.

If you *really* want to use STOMP over WebSockets then you'll have to use a STOMP client implementation that supports WebSockets (most do).

Keep in mind that ActiveMQ is a *broker*. It does not supply clients for all the protocols it supports. It only provides a JMS client because it is required in order to implement JMS. STOMP, for example, is a standardized protocol and anyone can implement a client which will work with any broker implementing STOMP. There are lots of STOMP client implementations available written in many different languages for many different platforms. Any good search engine should help you find one to fit your needs.

Comment: We are building a plugin based connector application. Taking data from several sources. They gave me information just like this;

We have an ActiveMQ server on this {host}. You can subscribe it with this url. "wss://host:port".

So how can i achive this? Because ActiveMQ says they are supporting ws protocols. But couldn't find any sample.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I tried stomp just like edited in my question. Can you check it?

Comment: On Stack Overflow you can't just keep on adding questions to your existing question. Every question should focus on a single issue otherwise it will likely be closed. I believe I answered your original question so it might be best to ask a *new* one with your latest STOMP client code.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me.
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174792/activemq-java-stomp-client-receives-read-timed-out