# ActiveMQ Java STOMP client receives SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, activemq-classic, stomp, consumer

There is an ActiveMQ server working on CentOS machine. I can connect and consume messages with TCP and HTTP using the OpenWire JMS client. However, When I tried with the ActiveMQ test STOMP client it throws this exception on `connection.receieve`;

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:224)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.readHeaderLine(StompWireFormat.java:174)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.readLine(StompWireFormat.java:167)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.parseAction(StompWireFormat.java:200)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.unmarshal(StompWireFormat.java:112)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection.receive(StompConnection.java:77)
    at tr.com.estherial.stomplistener.StompListener.main(StompListener.java:25)
```

Listener Class

```java
import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.Stomp;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompFrame;
 
public class StompListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        StompConnection connection = new StompConnection();
        try {
            connection.open("host", 61613);
            connection.connect("admin", "admin", "test");
            connection.subscribe("TEST_TOPIC", Stomp.Headers.Subscribe.AckModeValues.CLIENT);
            connection.begin("test"); 

            while (true) {
                try {
                    StompFrame message = connection.receive(10000); 
                    System.out.println(String.format("%s - Receiver: received '%s'", new Date(), message.getBody()));
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    // ignore
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the connector in `activemq.xml`:

```xml
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Did you get similar exception before?

Comment: Given your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66173308/java-wss-connection-could-not-create-transport-exception) on this subject it's worth noting that your code here is using normal a TCP socket to connect, not a WebSocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` is expected when the STOMP subscriber receives no message within the specified timeout. Once the client creates his subscription you need to *send* a message to the topic. At that point the client should receive the message and print it via your `System.out.println`.

Also, in ActiveMQ 5.x when subscribing to a destination from a STOMP client you need to prefix the destination name with either `/queue/` or `/topic/`. You aren't doing this in your application. Try using this:

```java
connection.subscribe("/topic/TEST_TOPIC", Stomp.Headers.Subscribe.AckModeValues.CLIENT);
```

Lastly, it's worth noting that you're using the *test* STOMP client from the ActiveMQ code-base. This client is used by ActiveMQ's internal test-suite to verify the broker implementation is working as expected. It's not meant for general use. Furthermore, if you're using Java you would be better off using a better performing and more full-featured client like the OpenWire JMS client or even the Qpid JMS client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I sent messages to TEST_TOPIC with producer(every second). It still getting SocketTimeoutException.  I can't use Openwire TCP client, customer does not allow that. They offer me two choices. STOMP or WSS.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Justin you made my day. Adding "/topic/" solved the problem. Thank you so much for your effort. Have a good weekend!

Answer (score 0):

You need a heartbeat every 10 seconds by sending just byte 10

```
    import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection;



public class StompExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        // Create a connection
        StompConnection connection = new StompConnection();
        
        connection.open("localhost", 61613);
        
        Socket socket = connection.getStompSocket();
        
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("login", "abcd");
        headers.put("passcode", "defghij");
        headers.put("heart-beat", "10000,10000");//heart-beat header newly added        
        
        connection.connect(headers);
        
        

        HeartBeatThread heartBeatThread = new HeartBeatThread(socket);
        heartBeatThread.start();
        

        SubscribeThread subscribeThread = new SubscribeThread(connection,"/topic/output"); 
        subscribeThread.start();
        
        heartBeatThread.join();
        subscribeThread.join();
        
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    
    public static String getNowISO() {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"); 
        df.setTimeZone(tz);
        String nowIso = df.format(new Date());
        return nowIso;
    }

}


import java.net.Socket;

public class HeartBeatThread extends Thread{
    
    public Socket socket;

    public HeartBeatThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("HeartBeatThread started");
        try {
             
            while(true) {
                
                
                System.out.printf("%s Sending Heartbeat message\r\n",StompExample.getNowISO());
                socket.getOutputStream().write(10);
                
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("HeartBeatThread finished");
    }

}

import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.Stomp;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompFrame;

public class SubscribeThread extends Thread{
    
    public StompConnection connection;
    public String subscribeTopic;

    public SubscribeThread(StompConnection connection,String subscribeTopic) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.subscribeTopic = subscribeTopic;

    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("SubscribeThread started");
        try {
            
            //subscribe to topic
            connection.subscribe(this.subscribeTopic, Stomp.Headers.Subscribe.AckModeValues.AUTO);

             
            while(true) {
                
               StompFrame message = connection.receive(0);
               
               System.out.printf("%s Received message:%s\r\n",StompExample.getNowISO(),message.getBody());
               
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SubscribeThread finished");
    }

}
```